# JQuery - Listen for a "scroll" event in an dynamically added/appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to detect scrolling with `JQuery` in an dynamically added element. Whereas the `.on()` method detects events like `click`, `scroll` events doesn't seem to be recognized.

*Example:*
https://jsfiddle.net/cwv9h0ur/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="add" value="add Divs"/>
<div id="container"></div>
Click: <div id="out"></div><br>
Scroll: <div id="out2"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#add").on("click",function(){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className="childDiv";
    div.innerHTML=" TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST ";
    $('#container').append(div);
})

$("#container").on("click",".childDiv",function (){
    $("#out").html("click detected");
    setTimeout(function(){$("#out").html("")},300)
});

$("#container").on("scroll",".childDiv",function (){
    $("#out2").html("scroll detected");
    setTimeout(function(){$("#out2").html("")},300)
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.container, .childDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background: lightgray;
    height: 100px;
    width: 80px;   
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll event doesn't bubble, so you cannot delegate it. However, you could capture event on all browsers which support it:

```
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    function(event){
        var $elm = $(event.target);
        if( $elm.hasClass('childDiv')){ // or any other filtering condition
           $("#out2").html("scroll detected");setTimeout(function(){$("#out2").html("")},300);
        }
    },
    true // Capture event
);
```

### -jsFiddle-